# CakePHP Simple table association assistance

Tags: cakephp

I'm really struggling with a table association in cakephp, all I'm trying to do is associate two tables together, however one table has two two foreign keys to the other table.

For some reason, I cannot get any information to be displayed in the field select form for home_id ....

Please see the database picture below and the associated code.

I'm really new to cakephp but feel if I can nail this it will be really useful  - any help is greatly appreciated.

[Database Schema](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/file/n5712772/db_design.png)

```
class SafcTeam extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'SafcTeam';
    var $displayField = 'name';
    var $validate = array(
            'name' => array(
                    'notempty' => array(
                            'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    ),
            ),
            'badge' => array(
                    'notempty' => array(
                            'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    ),
            ),
    );

    var $hasMany = array(
            'SafcTeam' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcEvent',
                    'foreignKey' => 'home_id',
            )
    );

}


class SafcEvent extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'SafcEvent';
    var $displayField = 'id';
    var $validate = array(
            'safc_matchtype_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'safc_league_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'home_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'away_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'streamer_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'safc_channel_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'comments' => array(
                    'notempty' => array(
                            'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    ),
            ),
            'safc_profile_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'safc_source_id' => array(
                    'numeric' => array(
                            'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    ),
            ),
            'event_info_url' => array(
                    'notempty' => array(
                            'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    ),
            ),
    );

    var $belongsTo = array(
            'SafcMatchtype' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcMatchtype',
                    'foreignKey' => 'safc_matchtype_id'
            ),
            'SafcLeague' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcLeague',
                    'foreignKey' => 'safc_league_id'
            ),
            'SafcChannel' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcChannel',
                    'foreignKey' => 'safc_channel_id'
            ),
            'SafcProfile' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcProfile',
                    'foreignKey' => 'safc_profile_id'
            ),
            'SafcSource' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcSource',
                    'foreignKey' => 'safc_source_id'
            ),
            'SafcTeam' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcTeam',
                    'foreignKey' => 'home_id'
            )
    );
```

}

Comment: Way too much code. You need to isolate the problem and ideally post a minimally representative sample.

Comment: Please close the question since it's answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use an alias for each of this relation of your SafcTeam Model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(

//relationship for your home_id fk
        'SafcHomeTeam' => array(
                'className' => 'SafcTeam',
                'foreignKey' => 'home_id'
        ),

 //relationship for your away_id key
            'SafcAwayTeam' => array(
                    'className' => 'SafcTeam',
                    'foreignKey' => 'away_id'
            )
    );
```

and also in the related safc team model :

```
var $hasMany = array(
        'SafcHomeTeam' => array(
                'className' => 'SafcEvent',
                'foreignKey' => 'home_id',
        ),
       'SafcAwayTeam' => array(
                'className' => 'SafcEvent',
                'foreignKey' => 'away_id',
        )
);
```

In your SafcEvents controller in the action add and edit add this:

```
//to respect cake conventions need the select list to be plural (Teams <--- with a s at the end)
    $safcHomeTeams = $this->SafcEvent->SafcHomeTeam->find('list');
$safcAwayTeams = $this->SafcEvent->SafcAwayTeam->find('list');
```

//also pass those list to the view
        $this->set(compact('SafcAwayTeams', 'SafcHomeTeams));

In the safcevent view Add and Edit

in the form section :

```
//to respect cake convention to construct your select input properly 
//you need to refere to the list established in the controller ($SafcHomeTeams by using $SafcHomeTeam_id <--singular + "_" + "id")
        echo $this->Form->input('SafcAwayTeam_id'); 
        echo $this->Form->input('SafcHomeTeam_id');
```

Comment: hi guignol, what you've posted makes perfect sense to me and it's how I originally understood the relationships to work.  But even after reverting to these I cannot get the drop down fields to populate with the teams in the events form.  DO I need to do anything else after I make the changes???

Comment: In case the edit is not understood can you post your controller's and view's code please. thanks

Comment: Hi guignol, I really appreciate your help with this - it's been driving me nuts for days.

Comment: I posed the controllers, views and models with some screen shots as it's still not doing what it's supposed to.  Thanks.  I can upload the code and db if required.

Comment: Hi guignol, I uploaded the files here... http://www.qfpost.com/file/d?g=UCk0G2cdC   there are two files 1) safc_cake.sql.gz (database) and 2) safc_cake.tar.gz which is the code.   Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't respect the conventions for Cake see my edit, the issue is fixed, please mark the question as solved, Enjoy.

Comment: Yep, that works!!!   Great.  Do you have any idea why the chosen values are not saved back to the database though?  I guess they need to be set somewhere, or is cake supposed to take care of it for me through the associations?

Answer (score 0):

Cake does not support complex FK out the box, you can define a relation with conditions like so

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'TheRelation' => array(
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array(
            ... conditions ...
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply dogmatic.  Would you be able to elaborate on your example please.  I really am a beginner with cake and the code I produced is simply from the design of the database and then the models and events that were baked against it.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html lot of explanation here. More than anyone can ever need.

Comment: I've read that article - before I even posted this.  Look at the code, I believe my associations are correct.  I can even see the correct SQL being ran to generate the list of values, but they are simply not selectable in my form.  If this is supposed to be a piece of cake then trying to do something what I would regard as very simply is turning out to be extremely complex and frustrating.